# Can I dismiss Gmail's warning about my filter forwarding my mail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I set up a filter on my personal gmail that forwards all mail from a certain domain to my work email. When I saved the filter, the following notification popped up at the top of my window:

[image]

("Your filters are forwarding some of your email to abby@stackoverflow.com. This notice will end in 7 days.")

Can I dismiss this message? Or must I look at it for 7 days? I clicked both "Review Settings" and "Learn more", and it's still there. There is no X or Dismiss button all the way on the right. Am I stuck with it for a week?

Comment: Uh, right when I submitted this question, the notification faded away. When it said "7 days" did it mean "7 minutes"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's going to be there for a week, but will only appear at login for a minute or two so you don't get [banner blindness](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/banner-blindness.html).

It's a security feature that should help remind you to double-check for any dubious forwarding filters during that time.

> #### [How long will I see this notice?](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=1355569)
>
> For about a week, this notice will appear for a few minutes each time you sign in to your account. Displaying the notification in this way helps ensure that you have a chance to see the notice, rather than someone who might try to gain unauthorized access to your account and use this setting improperly. The notice will disappear immediately if you choose to disable the forwarding filter setting, but that decision is up to you.